# Jenkins Remote backup

Tags: jenkins, cron

I am using `thin backup plugin`, but the problem with this is I can only give a backup directory that is on the local machine, what if I want to backup the `JENKINS_HOME` to some remote computer.

I understand I can set up a `cron job` in a script, but when to run that cron job?

I wish to have something like, as soon as the backup job is finished another job of moving the backup folder to some remote folder gets triggered!

Comment: Have you tried https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin?

Comment: It does not contain option for perforce

Comment: You do not need perforce.  You can host a git server internally and use it for saving configuration files. Another option is to create share on remote machine and connect to it using windows share, NTFS etc. Jenkins master can write to this location then.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as Jayan says:

- Windows: set up a network share drive from the target machine
- linux: mount a network share

...and point the backup to that.